# ubuntu 20.10 installation setup: unable to manage paritions. message: Your installation medium is on /dev/sda1

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning, installation

I'm having trouble to install the new Ubuntu 20.10. I made a bootable USB (via Ubuntu 20.04 Startup disk creator)
and booted it using UEFI. A fews steps into the setup let you manually manage the partitions on your disk(s) like: delete, resize, create partitions. For the current Ubuntu 20.04 installation I used LVM. So the root and my home mounts are on separate LVM volume groups.

The problem is that is cannot modify or change the current partition layout. When entering the disk management setup I briefly see a warning/error that states: `Your installation medium is on /dev/sda1, You will not be able to create,delete or resize any partitions.` The mentioned `/dev/sda1` partition is the bootable Ubuntu 20.10 USB drive.

Questions:

- What is happening and why?
- How can I fix this issue, so that I can manage the partition layout in the Ubuntu 20.10 installation wizard?

Note: an dist upgrade is no options for me.

Setup:

Dell XPS 15
Ubuntu 20.04
Intel i7
16GB RAM

Comment: The simplest way I've found is to let Ubuntu automatically manage disk setup, rather than manually doing so. It usually does a good, though slow, job upgrading. If you do not wish to keep the previous installation, then create unassigned space (removing the file system) where the previous installation dwelt; this is much faster but loses all files.

Comment: Why are you trying to install 20.10 when 21.04 is already out? 20.10 has only a few months of support left.

Comment: Today I also tried the same procedure with ubuntu 21.04 and I have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

If u r Upgrading from Ubuntu 20.04 to 20.10 , **UPGRADING** , Only if **UPGRADING** , The Older OS will be at the Disk , ie , /dev/sda1 . If U try to Part the sda1 , the Older OS will be Broken and It will Lead to Corruption in the Old Versions of Ubuntu . But , in the Improvements of the OS ,It Shows Error that the Installation of 20.10 is the Upgrade of 20.04 ( which is in sda1 ) to 20.10 ( which is to be installed over 20.04 ) . But if u try to part the sda1 , it is not possible to do it . Hope u can understand .

U can do a backup of ur data and make clean install of Ubuntu 20.10 in your machine by erasing ur disk and make ur partitions and install the OS .